# longtable/exam: longtable doesn't page-break inside the solution environment

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking, exam

In the following, the `longtable` is not breakable inside the solution environment. So, how to make the it respect `\newpage` to break the table over the two pages?

[image]

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,siunitx,multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question some question
        \begin{solution}
            \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
            \setlength\LTright{0pt}
            \begin{longtable}{
                    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    lr
                    *{2}{%
                        S[table-format=2.2,
                        round-precision=2,round-mode=places,
                        round-integer-to-decimal=true]%
                    }@{}}
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{H1 and H2} & H3 & H4 \\
                \midrule\endhead
                left & right & 78.79 & 23.45 \\
                \newpage
                left & right & 78.79 & 23.45 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{longtable}
        \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Longtable is finicky about being inside other environments, and some solution varieties will not break at all.  Basically you need a spliitable tabular without all the extra features (headers and footers) of longtable.

Comment: Interesting!  If you throw a \lipsum[1-6] into the solution, the longtable WILL break at the \newline.

Comment: longtable is (naturally!!) apparently not the culprit here, it seems the class is preventing page breaks in small sections, there is no page break here: `\documentclass[answers]{exam} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,siunitx,multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question some question
        \begin{solution}
aaa \par \pagebreak \par bbb
        \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo ^^^^^^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried putting the longtable inside a breakable tcolorbox and it didn't break; maybe, I did it wrong. If you wish, I can construct a MWE for this case.

Comment: @Diaa surely the aim of the game is to prove longtable is not at fault, not to find cases that break it :-) most breakable framed environments are likely to be "tricky" as they typically need access to the left and right margin to add the frame and longtable won't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't seem related to longtable, a simple solution of

```
aaa

\pagebreak

bbb
```

the page break is similarly ignored. The solution is set in a box and it seems the class does not always unbox it to allow page breaks.

As a pointer to a possible solution this version (just added a vspace) breaks but has a probably unwanted long white block at the end.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\newbox\mybox
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,siunitx,multicol}
\begin{document}
\setbox\mybox\vbox{
}

    \begin{questions}
        \question some question
        \begin{solution}
            \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
            \setlength\LTright{0pt}
            \begin{longtable}{
                    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    lr
                    *{2}{%
                        S[table-format=2.2,
                        round-precision=2,round-mode=places,
                        round-integer-to-decimal=true]%
                    }@{}}
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{H1 and H2} & H3 & H4 \\
                \midrule\endhead
                left & right & 78.79 & 23.45 \\
                \newpage
                left & right & 78.79 & 23.45 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{longtable}


\vspace{\textheight}
        \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note if you use longtable in a box you can usually get breaking to work but the head and foot will never be added so the lack of a table head on the second page is expected here (and not really fixable using longtable)

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information. If not mentioned in the manual, it would be helpful to announce this warning.

Comment: @Diaa well, the documented behaviour is that it doesn't work at all, to save in a box then allow page breaking you need `\unvbox` and there is no latex interface to that at all. But I did have some plans to have a documented interface for this sort of thing in version 5.